# Using Spring JpaRepository (backed with hibernate), is there a way to conditionally filter a field based on a GrantedAuthority?

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, spring-data

Using Spring Data, Spring Security, & Hibernate, is there a way to filter what columns are selected based on the GrantedAuthories the current user has?

So for example:

```
Entity
{
  field1;
  @HasGrantedAuthority('XYX')
  field2;
  field3;
}
```

Given the above example, I want field1 and field3 to always be returned, but field2 only if the user has GrantedAuthority == 'XYZ'.

```
SELECT * FROM Entity
vs
SELECT field1, field3 FROM Entity
```

---

I have looked into using Jackson's @JsonView, however this filters the data back to the client, which is good, but I want to filter it before that and prevent the server side application from even having the gated column. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-role-filter-json

Hibernate's @Filter seems to filter out an entire row, but I just want a specific column. Also, it doesn't seem there is native integration with Spring Data.

Comment: That's not possible on the entity level. One reason is that Java is static typed and then the value would be null and not missing like in JSON

Comment: I am also perfectly fine filtering at the spring data layer also.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no functionality to restrict the selection of attributes, depending on a person's authorities. But what you can do is two things:

> First, you can use lazy attribute loading

Use `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` and then load it in case a person has required authority.

> Second, you can use [projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) depending on availability of required authority.

Create if statement in your service layer and execute different repository methods depending on the result. In the negative case, you just retrieve projection, in positive case you retrieve the whole entity. This approach will bring you the best performance.